# Running Heroku through Terminal without success

Tags: node.js, web-services, heroku

I am trying to run through Terminal an app that I created on Heroku and I pushed my code to Heroku but when try to run in and my browser is up I get this error :

"An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. Please try again in a few moments.

If you are the application owner, check your logs for details."

In the Heroku logs I get this :

```
2016-04-16T08:06:37.028300+00:00 heroku[api]: Enable Logplex by tommyahav@gmail.com
2016-04-16T08:06:37.028300+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v2 created by tommyahav@gmail.com
2016-04-16T08:11:17.934258+00:00 heroku[api]: Scale to web=1 by tommyahav@gmail.com
2016-04-16T08:11:17.998349+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy d49f451 by tommyahav@gmail.com
2016-04-16T08:11:17.998349+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v3 created by tommyahav@gmail.com
2016-04-16T08:11:18.444546+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2016-04-16T08:11:18.444556+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2016-04-16T08:11:20.996842+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2016-04-16T08:11:24.058359+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-79-generic
2016-04-16T08:11:24.071525+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! argv "/app/.heroku/node/bin/node" "/app/.heroku/node/bin/npm" "start"
2016-04-16T08:11:24.075928+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! node v5.10.0
2016-04-16T08:11:24.077165+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! npm  v3.8.3
2016-04-16T08:11:24.104687+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
2016-04-16T08:11:24.104275+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
2016-04-16T08:11:24.126366+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-04-16T08:11:24.103431+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! missing script: start
2016-04-16T08:11:24.126822+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
2016-04-16T08:11:24.127038+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/npm-debug.log
2016-04-16T08:11:24.094153+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-04-16T08:11:24.104022+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! 
2016-04-16T08:11:25.136368+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2016-04-16T08:11:25.157435+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2016-04-16T08:11:25.156030+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2016-04-16T08:11:26.642881+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2016-04-16T08:11:29.940545+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-79-generic
2016-04-16T08:11:29.941387+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! argv "/app/.heroku/node/bin/node" "/app/.heroku/node/bin/npm" "start"
2016-04-16T08:11:29.941913+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! node v5.10.0
2016-04-16T08:11:29.942627+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! npm  v3.8.3
2016-04-16T08:11:29.944449+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-04-16T08:11:29.945912+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! missing script: start
2016-04-16T08:11:29.946108+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! 
2016-04-16T08:11:29.946249+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
2016-04-16T08:11:29.946394+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
2016-04-16T08:11:29.979159+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-04-16T08:11:29.979436+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
2016-04-16T08:11:29.979573+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/npm-debug.log
2016-04-16T08:11:31.099494+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2016-04-16T08:11:31.111785+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2016-04-16T08:11:41.679507+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=targil0.herokuapp.com request_id=b0e6c517-19bf-4fe9-b2ae-10a66a8531b7 fwd="79.183.166.1" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-04-16T08:11:42.011245+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=targil0.herokuapp.com request_id=5d888504-10b6-494c-97ba-300363c40ea8 fwd="79.183.166.1" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-04-16T08:12:33.276559+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=targil0.herokuapp.com request_id=a3bbb3d2-1b15-428f-8bc9-c084820d07b3 fwd="79.183.166.1" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-04-16T08:12:33.719142+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=targil0.herokuapp.com request_id=80f9fca8-8edd-40f1-876e-fd0d7c4629e8 fwd="79.183.166.1" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-04-16T08:12:34.583904+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=targil0.herokuapp.com request_id=f05e3322-020e-402a-abaf-3066b70f7524 fwd="79.183.166.1" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-04-16T08:12:35.024463+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=targil0.herokuapp.com request_id=abe440c1-e342-42c3-be8e-66534a27b9ed fwd="79.183.166.1" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-04-16T08:12:56.404658+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=targil0.herokuapp.com request_id=6fa70ad5-bf10-4eb0-b3c6-e449a90ffadf fwd="79.183.166.1" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-04-16T08:12:56.750374+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=targil0.herokuapp.com request_id=c188c52c-6117-4bcf-878c-a85892230160 fwd="79.183.166.1" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-04-16T08:13:44.397134+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=targil0.herokuapp.com request_id=9b61b821-4e3f-411f-89b0-2e8d50fdbc80 fwd="79.183.166.1" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-04-16T08:13:44.741220+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=targil0.herokuapp.com request_id=ff9b279c-6c23-4abc-bf9d-1b8f09964d5f fwd="79.183.166.1" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

Please help me and tell what I did wrong.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The important part is:

```
argv "/app/.heroku/node/bin/node" "/app/.heroku/node/bin/npm" "start"
missing script: start
```

Heroku is complaining it can't find the script you're telling it to launch.

Please print your `Procfile`, and scripts like `index.js` or `package.json`, depending on what your Procfile says.

If you didn't add a Procfile to your project root, then the default `npm start` is used, so you need a `"scripts.start"` property in the `package.json` file. So please print it :)

You may have a look at the Heroku guidelines ([Getting started](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs#define-a-procfile) and [Support](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support)) that deal with the Node deployment.